# how to fix the problem with strange error codes from t test

Tags: r

I have a df and I would like to run a ttest on it, however I keep getting error codes which I don't think make senesce. Could anyone take a look and see what might be the problem?

```
df<-structure(list(Order1 = c(0, 6, 6, 0, 6, 0, 0, 6, 6, 0, 6, 0), 
    AVAL = c(133, 116, 123, 137, 266, 244, 483, 443, 219, 265, 
    202, 197), ID = c("109", "109", "110", "110", "111", "111", 
    "113", "113", "114", "114", "115", "115")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(lsr)

pairedSamplesTTest( formula= AVAL ~ Order1 + (ID), data=df )
```

The error code that I got is:
[image]

Comment: No error running your example code above.

Comment: @caldwellst it is interesting about your comment.  Can you show the version of the package you ran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may need to convert the `tibble` to `data.frame`.  According to the documentation

> data - Optional data frame containing the variables.

```
pairedSamplesTTest( formula= AVAL ~ Order1 + (ID), data=as.data.frame(df) )
  Paired samples t-test 

Outcome variable:   AVAL 
Grouping variable:  Order1 
ID variable:        ID 

Descriptive statistics: 
                  0       6 difference
   mean     243.167 228.167     15.000
   std dev. 129.257 119.996     25.923

Hypotheses: 
   null:        population means equal for both measurements
   alternative: different population means for each measurement

Test results: 
   t-statistic:  1.417 
   degrees of freedom:  5 
   p-value:  0.216 

Other information: 
   two-sided 95% confidence interval:  [-12.204, 42.204] 
   estimated effect size (Cohen's d):  0.579 

Warning messages:
1: In pairedSamplesTTest(formula = AVAL ~ Order1 + (ID), data = as.data.frame(df)) :
  group variable is not a factor
2: In pairedSamplesTTest(formula = AVAL ~ Order1 + (ID), data = as.data.frame(df)) :
  id variable is not a factor
```

NOTE: Also, make sure to convert the group variable and id to `factor` to remove the warnings

---

was able to reproduce the same error in the OP's post when used `lsr` version `0.5.2`

```
> pairedSamplesTTest( formula= AVAL ~ Order1 + (ID), data=df )
Error in pairedSamplesTTest(formula = AVAL ~ Order1 + (ID), data = df) : 
  outcome variable must be numeric
```

Comment: For me 0.5.2 crashes after loading tibble.

Comment: @akrun any suggestion on how to output the stat results so it can be shared? Currently I take a screenshot each time. Not a good way for sure. 

Comment: the `broom` `tidy` methods are not implemented for this.  You can use `capture.output` as one way `capture.output(pairedSamplesTTest( formula= AVAL ~ Order1 + (ID), data=as.data.frame(df) ), file = 'yourfile.txt')`

Comment: @akrun This is a cool way. Is it possible to save it as pdf? I tried `pdf() ... dev.offf()` but could not get it to work,